# Comparison operators in h2o type environment returns type environment

Tags: r, types, boolean, h2o, comparison-operators

I am using H2O with R. When I am trying to compare two different elements of an H2O frame, I get an environment variable [1 row x 1 column]. I want to convert the type of this object to a numeric or Boolean type.

The reproducible example.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

>d <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,1))
>d.hex <- as.h2o(d)

>d.hex[1]
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
1                   1
[1 row x 1 column]

>typeof(d.hex[1])
[1] "environment"
```

I want a way to convert the following code so it returns Boolean value, or 0 or 1.

```
>d.hex[1] == d.hex[6]
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
1                   1    
[1 row x 1 column]
```

Expected Output

```
[1] True
```

or

```
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`d` is 1 column, 6 rows.

`d[,1]` (in R, and in the H2O R API) selects column 1. `d[1]` is another way to write that.

`d[1,]` selects row 1.

`d[1,1]` selects the element that is in row 1, cell 1. `d[6,1]` selects the element in row 6, cell 1.

So, `d.hex[1,1] == d.hex[6,1]` returns TRUE.

Where it seems the H2O R API differs from normal R, is in some of the row/column queries, especially with errors: `d[6]` gives an error, but `d.hex[6]` returns the first row; `d[,6]` gives an error, but `d.hex[,6]` returns a 0x0 data frame!

The moral of the story: when dealing with individual elements, explicitly specify both row and column.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the column types for a dataframe using `h2o.getTypes()`

in your case `h2o.getTypes(d.hex)`

H2O requires that each column only contains one type, so if you are comparing row 1 and row 6 in the same column it will have the same type. If you try to put multiple types in a single column H2OFrame it will assign one of them to NA.

Comment: Hi @Lauren, thanks for writing. But I think I couldn't explain the problem well. What I am expecting is the comparison operation should return a TRUE or 1 value in R format. But it's returning 1 [1 row x 1 column].